# VirtualHost и настройка .РФ домена

Tags: apache2, virtual-hosts

Нужно сделать зеркало для основного сайта "site.ru" (адрес для примера) в .рф зоне, то есть "сайт.рф". Домен куплен, DNS настроены. Но работать он отказывается всячески. Настраивается на apache2. Конечно же, настраиваю как положено, название сайта в punycode. 
В sites-available создан файл такого вида **xn--80aswg.xn--p1ai.conf**, у него внутри:

```
    ServerAdmin admin@site.ru
    ServerName xn--80aswg.xn--p1ai
    ServerAlias www.xn--80aswg.xn--p1ai
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site.ru/public_html

    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/site.ru/public_html
    UseCanonicalName Off

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options All -Indexes
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

После этого прописывается

> sudo a2ensite xn--80aswg.xn--p1ai

и

> sudo service apache2 restart

но сайт "сайт.рф" не начинает работать. До этого размещал кучу сайтов в зонах ru или com, никаких проблем не было. А тут засада. Что делать? Как можно провести отладку или почитать хотя бы лог ошибок при запросе на адрес "сайт.рф"?

Answer (score 1):

Логи хранятся в

```
var/logs/apache2
```

Хотя зависит от системы. Проблема в том, что конфиги апвча не понимают паникод. Скорее всего никаких ошибок, кроме недоступности этого адреса, вы не увидите. Покопайте в сторону модулей для РФ. Доменов, я думаю найдёте ответ, у меня тоже нет опыта с этими доменами

Answer (score 0):

У меня есть сайт site.ru и для него сайт.рф и site.com

Мой виртуальный хост выглядит примерно так:

```
ServerName site.ru
ServerAlias www.site.ru site.com www.site.com xn--80aswg.xn--p1ai.conf
```

То есть .рф - это алиас для .ru.